# Unity C# Animation is only playing the first frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to make a character play a specific animation when pressing the R button. I would like him to play the whole animation and then stop once it has run a cycle.

The issue now is that when I press "R" the animation only plays for a frame and no animation plays at all.

I started with this statement below.

```
void Update ()
{
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) 
 {
   anim.Play("Ready");
 }
}
```

I then read that it might be better to create a bool instead, if the bool is true -> play Animation.

```
public bool ready;

void Update ()
{
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
  {
     ready = !ready; 
  }
  if (ready == true)
  {
     anim.Play("Ready");
  }
}
```

When bool ready is true, the animation plays one frame and then the character becomes static. If the bool the gets false again, the character returns to his idle animation.

My latest attempt to making this work is by structuring the code like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
{
     ready = !ready;

     if(ready == true)
     {
         anim.Play("Ready");
     }            
}
```

However this only causes the animation to play a very small amount of frames until going back to the idle animation. Even though ready stays true.

I am not using the "Animator component" but rather the "Animation component" instead. This are the settings of it: [Animation Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sxg0.png)

Could it be the void Update() causing the issue? 
Also, is there a way to make sure the animation only plays for one cycle and then stops?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your animator window showing your animator controller configuration? It's likely that your animation is instantly returning back to your default state instantly instead of with an exit time. You can "has exit time" to true, and set it to "1" to make it complete the animation before returning.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Hi! I am actually not using the Animator component but rather the animation component instead. This is because I could not get the animator to work properly or calling a for example run animation properly. I included a screenshot of the animation component if that is of any help though.

Comment: Select `Ready` animation as default and see if it works fine by playing automatically.

Comment: If you are interrogating for the keypress continuously in some update loop, it is pretty obvious you are making multiple calls to the anim.Play() function.

Comment: @luci88filter `Input.GetKeyDown()` is called once on one key press.
`Input.GetKey()` is called continuously until you release the key after pressing.

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks valid. Are there chances that your imported animation isn't?
You should use the Animator as suggested:

- drop your clips in the Animator window,
- right click on the default state > "make transition", release on the next clip,
- create a parameter of type bool named "ready",
- assign this parameter in the transition from idle to the next state (select the arrow and click the "+" button at the bottom of the component in the Inspector window, select your parameter),
- in your script, you just have to call: 
  `myAnimator.SetBool("ready", true);`

There are a lot of benefits of using the Animator :
handle many animation clips, automatic transitions, preview, and more features with "humanoid" rigs (in the model import settings)...